# Strange ORDER BY requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set with several columns...
One column is a main grouper column with repeating values, and another is a NUMBER with boolean values (1,0)  like this:

```
grp bool
--- ----
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   0   
C   0
```

etc. of course i can order by grp, bool to get a listing like above.  What i would like is to get this listing to be first ordered by the grp, but then have the bool alternate values as best as possible...  something like the following:

```
grp bool
--- ----
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   0
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   1   
C   0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` to assign sequential values to each boolean in each grp.  Then use this sequential value for the ordering:

```
select grp, bool
from (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by grp, bool order by grp) as seqnum
      from dataset d
     ) d
order by grp, seqnum, bool desc;
```

Comment: @Randy . . . Each boolean is assigned a sequential value.  So, they will appear in pairs in the output.  I had missed the `bool` in the `order by` at first, so they might have been 10/01/01/10.  By ordering by the bool as the third argument, they will alternate.